# Access oxps (OpenXPS) document in .NET

Tags: .net, wpf, xps, xpsdocument

WPF has `System.Windows.Xps.Packaging.XpsDocument` to access a simple `.XPS` file.

Does any equivalent exist for an `OXPS` modification?

I tried opening `.oxps` file using `XpsDocument`, it doesn't work.